# Stored procedure used for Crystal Reports overwrites previous records

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have the following code to call a stored procedure to populate a Crystal Report. The problem is that the last record is the only one returned and is repeated throughout the report. It seems to be overwriting the previous records rather than returning the each record associated with the ID parameter. Am I missing something?

```
Dim idSQL As String = "SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table"

drID = objdata.getOLEDBDR(MSCON1, idSQL)

            While drID.Read
                IDall = drID(0)

              'GET DATA******************************
                sqlstr = "SELECT columnname FROM tablename WHERE Id = '" & IDall & "'"

                Dim DAscp As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, MSCON1)
                dsQRpt.EnforceConstraints = False

                DAscp.Fill(dsQRpt, "tablename")


              'GET DATA FROM SP***********************
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
                cmd.Connection = MSCON
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.CommandText = "NAME_OF_SP"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@month", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Output).Value = QtrMonth
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Output).Value = cboYear.SelectedValue
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Output).Value = IDall

          Dim DAms As New OleDbDataAdapter()

            DAms.SelectCommand = cmd

            'DAms.Fill(dsQRpt)
            DAms.Fill(dsQRpt, "SP_NAME")


              'Populate Report*********************************************************************
                QPrpt.Load(Server.MapPath("rptQuarterly.rpt"))
                QPrpt.SetDataSource(dsQRpt)
                crQtrProgress.ReportSource = QPrpt
                QPrpt.SetParameterValue("vPTSID", PTSall)
                crQtrProgress.DataBind()

            End While
```

Here's the stored procedure:

```
USE [DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NAME]
(
@month varchar(20),
@year varchar (4),
@id varchar (15)
)
AS

DECLARE @tmp table
(
ID nvarchar(10),
CategoryId nvarchar(5),
CategoryName nvarchar(50),
MDate datetime
)


DECLARE @i varchar(10)
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)


SET @i = 1
DECLARE @j varchar(10)
SET @j = 1


WHILE (@i <=28)
BEGIN
DECLARE @MIDDATE nvarchar(25)
DECLARE @MIDID nvarchar(15)
SET @MIDDATE = 'mh.MID_'+@i+'_DATE'
SET @MIDID = 'mh.MID_'+@i


IF (((@i= 9) OR (@i =12)) AND (@j = 1))
        BEGIN
            --SET @j = 2
            SET @MIDDATE = 'mh.MID_'+@i+'a_DATE'
            SET @MIDID = 'mh.MID_'+@i+'a'
        END  

 IF (((@i= 9) OR (@i = 12)) AND (@j = 2))
        BEGIN

            SET @MIDDATE = 'mh.MID_'+@i+'b_DATE'
            SET @MIDID = 'mh.MID_'+@i+'b'
       END 


SET @sql ='SELECT mh.ID, mc.CategoryId, mc.CategoryName, '+ @MIDDATE +'
FROM MHistory As mh, MCategories As mc WHERE mc.CategoryId = SUBSTRING('''+
@MIDID +''',8,10) AND mh.ID = ''' + @id + ''' AND mh.Hist_Yr = ' + @year + '
AND mh.Hist_Month = ''' + @month + ''' ORDER BY mh.ID'
INSERT INTO @tmp
EXEC (@sql)

IF (((@i= 9) OR (@i=12)) AND (@j = 1))
                  BEGIN
                  IF @i= 9 SET @i = 9
                  IF @i =12 SET @i = 12
                  SET @j = 2
                  END 
  ELSE
                  BEGIN
                    SET @i = @i + 1
                    SET @j = 1
                  END 
 END

----SET @i = @i + 1
SELECT 
ID AS ID,
CategoryId AS CategoryId,
CategoryName AS CategoryName,
MDate AS MDate

from @tmp
```

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure code?

Comment: Sure thing, I added it to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Can you briefly describe the logic you are using in your procedure?

Comment: I don't see any statement that will run the command for the stored procedure in your VB.Net code. You have defined a command object for the stored procedure but no method is called like `Fill` or `ExecuteReader`. This means the data from stored procedure will not be returned.

Comment: It is taking the parameters to be used in the query. The MID_xx_Date fields are numbered (ex MID_12_DATE) so we set up a loop to populate the variable @i in MID_@i_Date. For 9 and 12 there are a and b values which is why we add those letters in the conditional statement. Then the values sent to the report.

Comment: The stored procedure is connected to the report and runs fine with single records but when multiple records are returned only the last one appears on the report in multiple places. Ex If 3 records are returned the values in the SP are repeated 3 times

Comment: As a first step, I would try to make sure whether the stored procedure is running every time report is rendered and also what is the result set procedure is returning. You could create a another table to contain the results of the query in your procedure and then after each report rendering check that table for what was actually returned by the procedure.  This will tell you if the procedure is working as expected. So dump the data from last query into this new table, and do this just before the final SELECT in the procedure.

Comment: I've confirmed that it is working but each record is being overwritten by the next. I think the problem has something to do with the parameter setup in the VB rather than the SP but not sure where

Comment: Your first query is always going to return a single record since its filtering on a primary key column value of  `Id`. Also, this query seems to be the data source of your report. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the query for the report's data source is always returning a single record since your datasource query is filtering on `Id` which I believe is the primary key of `tablename`.

```
'GET DATA******************************
            sqlstr = "SELECT columnname FROM tablename WHERE Id = '" & IDall & "'"

            Dim DAscp As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, MSCON1)
            dsQRpt.EnforceConstraints = False

            DAscp.Fill(dsQRpt, "tablename")
```

**Also, I would suggest that you verify if the stored procedure** is getting called by the report with correct parameters. You could do this by populating a custom table just before the last `SELECT` in your stored procedure.  In this custom table you could log the values of parameters and anything else you think is relevant to the situation.

You can use following queries to do this logging.

**Create custom tables for logging**

```
CREATE TABLE CustomLoggingTable (Parameters varchar(max), RunDate DateTime);
CREATE TABLE CustomResultsTable (ID int, CategoryId int, CategoryName varchar(500),
                                                                         MDate DateTime);
```

Add the query below as the last part in your procedure ( the last SELECT in this code is the original SELECT you have and you should not change it, but just place the other part before it)

**Log your stored procedure**

```
--log procedure parameters
INSERT INTO CustomLoggingTable ( Parameters, RunDate) 
select '@month = ' + isnull(@month,'')  + ', @year = ' + isnull(@year,'') 
                                       + ', @id = ' + isnull( @id,''), getdate() ;

--log result set being returned into a custom table
DELETE from CustomResultsTable;
INSERT into CustomResultsTable (ID, CategoryId, CategoryName, MDate)
SELECT 
ID AS ID,
CategoryId AS CategoryId,
CategoryName AS CategoryName,
MDate AS MDate
from @tmp

--this is your last statement in procedure for returning final result set
SELECT 
ID AS ID,
CategoryId AS CategoryId,
CategoryName AS CategoryName,
MDate AS MDate
from @tmp
```

After above setup, you can view exactly what happened when your stored procedure was called. The `CustomResultsTable` will be refreshed every time with the latest result set returned, while  `CustomLoggingTable` will add a new record for each run of the procedure.

Comment: Isn't this query populating your report?

Comment: The report has two detail sections. That query populates the first one which works fine. The SP populates the 2nd which overwrites the previous records.

Comment: For the stored procedure part of VB.Net code where is the `Fill` method being called? I don't see it in the VB.Net code that you posted.

Comment: My bad, I missed it when I copied over. It's there now and looks like Dim DAms As New OleDbDataAdapter()

                DAms.SelectCommand = cmd

                'DAms.Fill(dsQRpt)
                DAms.Fill(dsQRpt, "SP_NAME")

Comment: So that eliminates one possibility.  Now I would suggest that you do some logging  as I explained in my answer when the stored procedure is called, so at least you would know if correct parameters are getting passed to the stored procedure. This would be very vital in your situation since the stored procedure report is your problem.

Comment: I did confirm that the correct IDs are being sent to the stored procedure and tested it by having it return a different number of records using TOP in the query but it still only displays the last one

Comment: You have three parameters being passed to the procedure, so it would be good if you can log them to a custom table  from inside the stored procedure. Also dump the final result in your stored procedure into a custom table.

Comment: The logging solution I have recommended in my answer  will only help unearth any issues that are otherwise very difficult to see. Logging always helps.Note that it will not change/impact the result being returned or the logic of your stored procedure.